# Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 10000000 cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code but I'm getting the following error after running it.
Is there any way to resolve this?
The data that I'm retrieving has about that amount of cell but it may be retrieving blank rows but all the rows has formulas.

N# of rows per file:

- uno: 72850
- dos: 72850
- tres: 72850
- cuatro: 72850
- cinco: 72850

Total: 364250

[image]

```js
function test() {
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id2')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('uno')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id2')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('dos')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id3')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('tres')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id4')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('cuatro')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id5')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('cinco')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
};
```

[image]

Comment: It's time to remove some data or move to another spreadsheet

Comment: How can I run this script automatically

Comment: What makes you think that running it automatically would eliminate the Exception?

Comment: Nothing, but I eliminate extra columns and now is running ok

Comment: You can run it with a trigger

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to be related to current [Spreadsheets limits](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603) in Google Sheets as [@Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) mentioned, currently the limit is the following:

> ​Up to 10 million cells or 18,278 columns (column ZZZ) for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.

Creating a new sheet could do the work as the limits apply per sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `getLastRow()` by `getLastDataRow()` after adding

```
Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function(col){
  var lastRow = this.getLastDataRow();
  if (col == null){col='A'}
  var range = this.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }  
};
```

so ...

```
function test() {
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id2')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('uno')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastDataRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastDataRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id2')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('dos')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastDataRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastDataRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id3')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('tres')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastDataRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastDataRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id4')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('cuatro')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastDataRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastDataRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id5')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('cinco')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastDataRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastDataRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
};
Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function(col){
  var lastRow = this.getLastDataRow();
  if (col == null){col='A'}
  var range = this.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }  
};
```

Comment: Where would this go in the code?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could adapt it to the code

Comment: not sure at all it will work!

Comment: I have updated the post with the error message.

Comment: ok, you have probably reach the limit! Do you know how rows there are in each file?

Comment: Yes, is a total of 364250. The post was updated